# I want to sum the values present in different sheets(located in different spreadsheets) in a new google sheet using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I want to add values present in different sheets(located in different spreadsheets) in a new google sheet using google app script. I am new to this and have no idea how to proceed. I would appreciate if someone could help me with the same.

Comment: Hi Ishan, do you have some code that you have tried? If so, please share that here so folks can give you inputs on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add your own spreadsheet id's and sheetnames to the Data Sheet and then all the data in those sheets will be displayed on the Comparisons Sheet.

```
function getData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ish=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var iA=ish.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Comparisons');
  dsh.clearContents();
  dsh.getRange('A1').setValue('Displaying Data from selected spreadsheets list in Data Sheet.').setFontWeight("Bold");
  for(var i=1;i<iA.length;i++) {
    if(iA[i][0] && iA[i][1]) {
      var css=SpreadsheetApp.openById(iA[i][0]);
      var csh=css.getSheetByName(iA[i][1]);
      var vA=csh.getDataRange().getValues();
      var desc=Utilities.formatString('Data from %s',iA[i][1]);
      dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(desc).setFontWeight("Bold");
      dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the format of my Data Sheet:

[image]

This is what my Comparisons Sheet looks like after running it with two other spreadsheets listed:

[image]

**Adding Data from other Spreadsheets**

```
function getData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ish=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var iA=ish.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sum');
  dsh.clearContents();
  for(var i=1;i<iA.length;i++) {
    if(iA[i][0] && iA[i][1]) {
      var css=SpreadsheetApp.openById(iA[i][0]);
      var csh=css.getSheetByName(iA[i][1]);
      dsh.appendRow([csh.getRange(iA[i][2]).getValue()]);
    }
  }
  var rg=dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1).setFormula("=Sum(" +  dsh.getRange(1,1,i-1,1).getA1Notation() + ")");
  rg.offset(0,1).setValue("Total").setFontWeight("Bold")
}
```

Data Sheet:

[image]

Sum Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess I was not clear enough, what I want is to perform addition of values from 2 sheets and show the sum in new sheet. Would you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I added a second version that handles that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to access the different spreadsheets by their IDs or names, the respective sheets by name, choose the [ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) from which you want to copy and in which you want to paste and set the values. Note that to use the [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) method requires that your origin range and destination range have the same dimensions. Consult the Apps Script reference for more information.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet_origin1=SpreadsheetApp.openById("your spreadsheet ID 1").getSheetByName("name of sheet 1");
var sheet_origin2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("your spreadsheet ID 2").getSheetByName("name of sheet 2"); 
var sheet_destination=SpreadsheetApp.openById("your spreadsheet ID 3").getSheetByName("name of sheet 3"); 

//choose your range of interest  
var range1=sheet_origin1.getRange("A1:D3");
var range2=sheet_origin2.getRange("A1:E2"); 
var destinationrange_1=sheet_destination.getRange("A1:D3");
var destinationrange_2=sheet_destination.getRange("A4:E5");  

//Here you add the values from different sheets to to different ranges of the destination sheet  
destinationrange_1.setValues(range1.getValues());
destinationrange_2.setValues(range2.getValues());
}
```

If you want to sum the values of cells in different sheets and paste the result in the corresponding cell of the destination sheet - you can do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {

var sheet_origin1=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wUzNCzdQyVCe8VkZghTUQz_0QEAiU6ONpW45kiGE_2U").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet_origin2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CD0yp_0_5u-UX_9J4Az38NirAMMvu5G7kksmLz3S0cw").getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var sheet_destination=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();


//define range as a string in A1 notation
var range="A1:D3"  
var values1=sheet_origin1.getRange(range).getValues();
var values2=sheet_origin2.getRange(range).getValues(); 
var destinationrange=sheet_destination.getRange(range);

//Here you sum the values of equivalent cells from different sheets
  for(var i=0; i<values1.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0; j<values1[0].length;j++)
    {
       sum=values1[i][j]+values2[i][j];
       destinationrange.getCell(i+1,j+1).setValue(sum);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I guess I was not clear enough, what I want is to perform addition of values from 2 sheets and show the sum in new sheet. Would you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Do you want to sum e.g. the values from cell A1 from sheet 1 and A1 from sheet 2, and assign the result to cell A1 in the result sheet?